# match height of highest tab - to set slide height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a variation of the jquery idtabs within a accordian/slide tab.

The slide height is set by the content of the #tab1 content however this often not the tallest of tabs -as a result content in other tabs may not be fully visible.

The slide code is as follows:

```
                <script>
            $(function(){
                var slideHeight = 305; // px
                var defHeight = $('#wrap').height();
                if(defHeight >= slideHeight){
                    $('#wrap').css('height' , slideHeight + 'px');
                    $('#read-more').append('<a href="#">SHOW MORE</a>');
                    $('#read-more a').click(function(){
                        var curHeight = $('#wrap').height();
                        if(curHeight == slideHeight){
                            $('#wrap').animate({
                              height: defHeight
                            }, "normal");
                            $('#read-more a').html('SHOW LESS');
                            $('#gradient').fadeOut();
                        }else{
                            $('#wrap').animate({
                              height: slideHeight
                            }, "normal");
                            $('#read-more a').html('SHOW MORE');
                            $('#gradient').fadeIn();
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            });

            </script>
```

I am convinced using variation of the following in the original code should solve the issue but I can seem to merge the scripts successfully.

```
                <script>

                $(function(){

                var heighest = 0;
                $('#wrap').each(function(){
                    heighest = ($(this).height() > heighest) ? $(this).height() : heighest;

                });

                $('#wrap').css('height',heighest + 'px');

            });

            </script>
```

Any help/suggests would be appreciated -this is not my field, I'm a pictures man.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your issue in a fiddle

Comment: Fiddle is here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ty4/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. Notice that there is no element `#wrap`, and even if there was, `$('#wrap').each(...)` would always just act upon the one element. Also, consider which elements have to be shown within the visible area

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var slideHeight = 50, // px
            wrapHeight = $('#wrap3').height();

        $('#wrap3 .usual2 div').each(function(){
            wrapHeight = ($(this).outerHeight() > wrapHeight) ? $(this).outerHeight() : wrapHeight;
        });
        defHeight = wrapHeight + slideHeight;

        if(defHeight >= slideHeight) {
            (...etc)
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution worked however I needed to remove the "+ slideHeight" in the "defHeight =" statement; to clear the additonal white space added by the combination of the 2.